# create 2 vertical scrollbars in layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview

In my layout there is one Listview and multiple controls. If I create scroll view

listview scroll does not work. If I remove scroll view listview scrolling is works.

how to get both scrolls working?

Thanks in advance,
Durai

Comment: why do you want a listview to be included in ScrollView because listview is itself auto-scrollable? And yes, Post your XML layout which you have tried so far.

Comment: Listview can not be included in scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need both (ScrollView and ListView), try to reduce the width of the ListView, so that you have some free space on the left or right of the ListView, where the user can touch and scroll the ScrollView below it. Otherwise the ListView will always receive the scroll events.

I mean it like this:

```
-----------------------
I               I     I
I               I     I
I               I     I
I    ListView   I     I
I               I     I
I               I     I
I               I     I
-----------------------

<---- ScrollView  ---->
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get both to scroll. You can define weight for your `Listview` while wrapping its content.

Otherwise if other controls take too much of the screen space then, instead of using a `Listview`, Use a `Linearlayout` to hold your items with a `ScrollView` as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

ListView comes with its own scroll and extends till the length of the list. You cannot club scroll and listview together.